# Overlay flash displayobject on Starling Stage3D

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework, displayobject

I'm using Starling to build a space shooter game in ActionScript, and I'd like to draw simple lasers using the normal graphics primitives that Flash provides.

How can I set the translation matrix for Flash to be the same as for any given Starling DisplayObject?

```
transform.matrix = starlingDO.getTransformationMatrix(starlingDO.root);
```

comes close, but it seems it does not take into account viewport scaling of Starling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Starling Graphics Extension here https://github.com/StarlingGraphics/Starling-Extension-Graphics ? 
It's easy to use and you don't have to use native Flash display objects.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. I've basically solved lasers by using ordinary quads. I'm aware of the performance implications of using Flash display objects, but the question remains unanswered for now. :-)